# Module not found: Can't resolve 'action.types' error

Tags: reactjs, redux

action.types is in context folder and Contacts is in components folder. I have tried solving the issue but it's still throwing module not found error. I have used action.types in other files as well but it's not throwing any error there. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

This is my action.types file

```
//TODO: SET_LOADING, SET_CONTACT,
// CONTACT_TO_UPDATE, SET_SINGLE_CONTACT

export const SET_LOADING = 'SET_LOADING'
export const SET_CONTACT = 'SET_CONTACT'
export const CONTACT_TO_UPDATE = 'CONTACT_TO_UPDATE'
export const SET_SINGLE_CONTACT = 'SET_SINGLE_CONTACT'
```

This is my Contacts file

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

  import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Spinner } from "reactstrap";
  import Contact from "../components/Contact";
  import { MdAdd } from "react-icons/md";
  import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
  import { ContactContext } from "../context/Context";
  import { CONTACT_TO_UPDATE } from "../context/action.types";

  const Contacts = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(ContactContext);

    // destructuring contacts and isLoading from state
    const { contacts, isLoading } = state;

    // history hooks from react router dom to get history
    const history = useHistory();

    // handle fab icon button click
    // will set in state of the contact to update and send it to the contact/add route
    const AddContact = () => {
      //TODO: use dispatch to send user to add contact screen
      dispatch({
        type:CONTACT_TO_UPDATE,
        payload:null,
        key:null
      })
      history.push("/contact/add");
    };

    // return loading spinner
    if (isLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="Center">
          <Spinner color="primary" />
          <div className="text-primary">Loading...</div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Container className="mt-4">
        {/* TODO: Loop through FIREBASE objects  */}
        {contacts.length === 0 && !isLoading ? (
          <div className = 'Center text-large text-primary'>No contacts listed</div>
        ):(
          <ListGroup>
            {Object.entries(contacts).map(([key,value])=>(
              <ListGroupItem key = {key}>
                <Contact contact={value} contactKey={key}/>
              </ListGroupItem>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
        <MdAdd className="fab icon " onClick={AddContact} />
      </Container>
    );
  };

  export default Contacts;
```

This is the error

```
./src/components/Contact.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'action.types' in '/home/rajkirito/Web development/React/eleven-firebase-database/src/components'
```

Comment: is the extension is .types??

Comment: it is action.types.js

Comment: check the path to the folder once again. That can be a reason